# How prove this linear algebra $AB=BA$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

> Suppose $A,B\in M_{n}(\Bbb C)$ satisfies for $\forall a,b\in \Bbb C,aA+bB$ is always diagonalizable.
>
> Show that
> $$AB=BA.$$

Comment: Consider $A=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right), B=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&0\\1&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$.  We have $AB\neq BA$, and $aA+bB$ diagonalizable for all values of $a,b$ except $a+b=0$.

Comment: Thank you ,but $a,b\in C$.

Comment: @math110, does $C$ stand for complex numbers?

Comment: yes,@Easy,Thank you

Comment: My example shows that the condition $aA+bB$ is very important, and it's not enough to just consider some values of $a,b$ as @Easy did.

Comment: @vadim123, yes, I confess my idea doesn't work. Basically, the condition would imply $A,B$ share the same eigenspaces, and hence they can be diagonalised simultaneously. But not sure how to show this so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a non trivial result. It has indeed be the object of papers:

- [1] T. S. Motzkin and Olga Taussky, [*Pair of matrices with property $L$*](https://circle.ubc.ca/handle/2429/40177), Transactions of the American Mathematical Society
  Vol. 80, No. 2 (Nov., 1955), pp. 387-401
- [2] Shmuel Friedland, [*A generalization of the Motzkin-Taussky theorem*](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379581902238),  Linear Algebra and Its Applications - LINEAR ALGEBRA APPL , Volume 36, March 1981, Pages 103–109

Comment: The second link seems unavailable.

Comment: @FrankScience Thank you, I've edited.

Comment: Thank you,it's very nice.@DavideGiraudo

Comment: I hope if there's some pure elementary approach.

Comment: I think [this article](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1952-073-01/S0002-9947-1952-0049855-8/S0002-9947-1952-0049855-8.pdf) is more direct.

Comment: [It](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1955-080-02/S0002-9947-1955-0086781-5/) is also related, Motzkin & Taussky's original proof.